# HTML5 : Page Fold Effects

Tags: html, css, mootools

There are quite a number of page flip / curl effects using HTML5 & CSS3 in the Internet, but it seems I cannot find any page fold effects ( fold up the page both left & right side to middle ).

Any advice / suggestion on using which tool ? Mootools ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at CSS3 3d-transformations ;)

see http://2012.beercamp.com/ (source-code) and for the beginning http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

EDIT: to actually achieve your folding-up effect, you'd have to add 2 `<div>s` that get 3d-transformed when hovering/whatever. Actually it's not that hard, when you understand the basics ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a js lib - [oriDomi](http://oridomi.com/), which can help you create foldup effect

Try demo [here](http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120831-fold-up-html-elements-like-paper/)

Comment: Thanks for the demo link. Is there user interactions available? I tried the demo in Chrome, but there is no mouse interactions.